Compare cell types human iPCS lines and human prefrontal cortex
I'm a bioinformatician with less knowledge in biology.
I'm working with human brain cells. I have 2 different sequencing datasets. One was derived from human iPCS lines, and another was obtained from postmortem human prefrontal cortex cells.
These two datasets were provided with their own cell type annotations and they are two different from each other.
What I'm doing is try to integrate the two dataset first. But the result displays that these two datasets are too seperated and I cannot find any common group of cells between the two.
May I ask, if anything of their properties or the cell types of human iPCS lines and postmortem human prefrontal cortex cells are in common? Or are they too different?
Sorry if my question is not correct, because I don't really understand what makes them different. I saw so many papers have been working on iPCS to study brain diseases, so I supposed there must be common things between them.
Thanks in advance for any explanation.

"the result displays that these two datasets are too seperated" - The "result" doesn't display anything, it sounds like you're using some software package that you haven't described to us. It seems like it's not just the biology you're not familiar with, but you don't know how your software works, either. That's a dangerous place to be in. Overall, it's dangerous to try to study biology questions without knowledge of biology, and you're not going to be able to patch the gap with SE Q&A. Plus I assume you're talking about "iPSC" cells and keep writing "iPCS".

Your deceased-samples weren't from some peculiar circumstance involving unbuffered formaldehyde, were they?

Trivial explanation: you have a batch effect that makes comparing the two datasets possibly non-informative (Jiminy's question is one case of this). More generally, iPSCs are pluripotent cells, whereas cortex cells are (I'd assume) fully and fairly dramatically differentiated cells. You'd expect them to behave quite differently!
